# Sequelize - Is it possible to search all columns of a table with Op.or operator?

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, sequelize.js

In a project with NodeJS and ExpressJS, using Sequelize, I'm attempting to implement server-side pagination and searching

```
const products = await Product.findAll({
      where: {
        [Op.and]: [
          {
            status: {
              [Op.ne]: -1
            },
          },{
            [Op.or]:[
              {
                name:{
                  [Op.substring]:searchString
                }
              },{
                category:{
                  [Op.substring]:searchString
                },
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      limit: rows,
      offset: offset
    });
```

Now this allows me to search in the **name** and **category** columns, but Product's table has like 10 columns, Client's table has like 15 columns, is there a way to get something like

`WHERE any-column LIKE "%searchString%"`

```
where:{
    [Op.or]:[
        {any-column}:{
            [Op.substring]:searchString
        }
    ]
}
```

Or is my only option to add each column manually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all columns are string type, you can use `CONCAT_WS` function to search in a whole combined string.

```js
const searchCols = ['name', 'description', 'category'].map(sequelize.col);

await Product.findAll({
    where: {
        status: {
            [Op.ne]: -1
        },
        [Op.where]: Sequelize.where(Sequelize.fn('CONCAT_WS', ' ', ...searchCols), 
                                    Op.like,
                                    `%${searchString}%`)
    }
})
```